# Is a space allowed between #! and the first character of the path?

Tags: linux, shebang

In the language i work with, "#" does not start a comment.
So i have to find a way to pass the first shebang line without yielding an error.
A trick could do the job provided that some space is/are allowed after the heading #!, i mean writting

```
#! /usr/path/to/the/bin/to/call/to/run/me
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/path/to/the/bin/to/call/to/run/me
```

I have no linux installation available to do the test myself.

Would this shebang work?

Comment: More properly answered at [Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/197080)

Answer (score 4):

The shebang (`#!`) is a 16-bit kernel-interpreted magic "number" (actually `0x23 0x21`).  Thereafter, the kernel program loader (following the `exec`-family call) attempts to execute the remainder of the line to handle the remainder of the containing file's content.  Many, if not most modern kernels disregard preceding spaces to the command that follows the shebang.  As such, `#! /bin/bash`, `#! /usr/bin/perl`, and the like, should be acceptable with most modern kernels.  That said, a shebang with no following space is far more commonly seen.

*Note, and FYI, the executable and linkable format (ELF) magic number is 32-bits: `0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46` or `[DEL] [E] [L] [F]`.*

Comment: Thanks. So i look forward to be quite optimistic, before i can check it. This would allow to fix a long-standing issue, without to change the core of/recompile the software. However, it also requires to write a short file named #!.ext, and i am wondering about side effects of these special characters in file name for Linux. But that's another question (anyway, thanks @john-kugelman for having added the linux tag)

Comment: I'm not clear on the issue you're trying to solve.  Why are you attempting to write a file named `#!.ext`!?  I'd be happy to help, if I can. :-/

Comment: #!.ext will contain the function definition named #!(). Then, for the language, when processing the first shebanged line of the script, #! will be seen as this function, and /user//..... as its input arguments (that's why the space is needed). And all will go smoothly without any error.
Having a filename equal to the function name is a requirement for this language, to be able to include this function in a standard library that will be automatically loaded at the software's startup.