Ubuntu Shell Script Runs in Terminal but Stops when in Service File
I am trying to create an Ubuntu Service on an EC2 Ubuntu Instance that simply executes a shell script that runs a python scripts. When running the shell script in terminal, the python executes perfectly. When the service runs, however, the shell script runs but hangs when it gets to the python script.
The shell script:
#! /usr/bin/bash -l

echo "running!"
/home/ubuntu/absolute/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/absolute/path/to/pythonscript.py

The Ubuntu Service:
[Unit]
Description=Python Script Descriptions
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart="/home/ubuntu/shell_script.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

The echo command runs in the shell script so I know it the script runs, but the script stops before any python is run and simply hangs. There is no output of any kind when I check journalctl.
The python script itself is a function called within a 'While True' loop in an attempt to have the function run again after it completes. It requires a network connection to ping a 3rd party API and put the data into an AWS Dynamodb database, but does not require any human interaction nor any GUI nor any any access to existing drives on the server. The goal is to have this script running 24/7, entirely in the background.
Any help on this issue would be massively appreciated, thank you.

Does your script need to source/activate the virtual environment before it runs?  I.E. Are there libraries installed in the virtual environment that may also be install for you (dear user) that root (which is what seems to be running the service, since you don't call out a user to run as) may not have access to?

#! /usr/bin/bash -l there should not be a space. also try this #!/usr/bin/env bash and make sure to chmod +x /home/ubuntu/shell_script.sh

@TGGowda Space is allowed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102710/is-a-space-allowed-between-and-the-first-character-of-the-path

@Barmar I stand corrected! maybe the issue is with either login shell (bash -l) or the lack of execute permissions (chmod +x)

Check the systemd log for error messages when it tries to run the service.

@VoNWooDSoN you are correct: even with activating the virtual environment it still would not run, but adding User= to the service file fixed it. Thank you everyone for your help!

I was able to solve the issue by adding a 'User=' field to the [Service] section of the service file. It is very likely that the issue was just access to Python libraries used by the script.
I don't know why the script failing to execute would not show up in the systemd logs, but I can confirm that adding 'User=' resolved the issue.
